# I broke something with usermod

Tags: authentication, user-permissions

Debian Buster, KDE-Plasma

I'm a newbbie on Linux and Programming and I broke something installing Python 3.8 and I can't find a solution because I can;t really find what I did. I'm really interested on understand what's happenig, because I'd like to learn a lot about Linux, but I came from Windows, and user's accounts and permissions are still a mistery for me.

I have an idea about what I did wrong and I can describe the symptoms.
what I did wrong: I used something similar to "usermod -a -G root my_user_name" to give sudo permissions to my user account.

The symptoms are:

I lost my login-name in login screen under Plasma.  No user account, neither user icon. Before breaking the system I only had to write password, now I also have to enter my user name too.
Login screen is from Gnome, switch-user screen is from Plasma.

On desktop everything is ok, but when I open Konsole, my user starting folder is /root, and root is starting in home/user folder. I'm completly lost.

Something has also changed on permissions, because though I'm not using SU account, managing some installations and some operations ask for used password, when I was used to enter Root password.

I've been searching internet and I can't find what I modified to get this behaviour.

I took a look at /etc/passwd andthe only thing that look strange is a line where my complete name is written and the starting folder is /bin/bash. If I change this into /home/user, things get worse, because konsole complies about a problem and cant be started. I also looked at etc/groups and can't figure out if something is wrong .

I don't want to touch any more before getting a clear idea about the situation, because system is full of apps and took me a lot of hours to configure it like this.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed part of the problem. Now I have SDDM login screen. I reinstalled SDDM default theme (Breeze). Now I can switch between other themes, not a lot because many of the depends on Qtquick-controls 2.5 and I have 4.1x installed.

What still makes me pull my hairs is how the hell I've been able to swap user and root login folders with just an instruction (usermod)